# Web Scraping - Table Name

Tags: r, web-scraping

New to webscraping.

I am trying to scrape a site. I recently learnt how to get information from tables, but I want to know how to get the table name. (I believe table name might be wrong word here but bear with me)

Eg - https://www.msc.com/che/about-us/our-fleet?page=1

MSC is shipping firm and I need to get the list of their fleet and information on each ship.
I have written the following code that will retrieve the table data for each ship.

```
df <- MSCwp[i,1] %>% 
    read_html() %>% html_table()
```

MSCwp is the list url. This code gets me all the information I need about the ships listed in the webpage expect its name.

Is there any way to retrieve the name along with the table?

Eg - df for the above mentioned website will return 10 tables. (corresponding to the ships in the webpage). df[1] will have information about the ship Agamemnon but I am not sure how to retrieve the shipname along with the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pull the names out from the main page.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr) 

url <- "https://www.msc.com/che/about-us/our-fleet?page=1"
page <- read_html(url)

names <- page %>% html_elements("dd a") %>% html_text()  
names

[1] "AGAMEMNON"       "AGIOS DIMITRIOS" "ALABAMA"         "ALLEGRO"         "AMALTHEA"        "AMERICA"         "ANASTASIA"      
[8] "ANTWERP TRADER"  "ARCHIMIDIS"      "ARIES"
```

In this case I am looking for the text in the "a" child node of the "dd" nodes.

Comment: Ahhh. Got it. For some reason I was stuck with the idea the table itself will somehow have the name somewhere and I wasn't extracting it properly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can I ask how you determined the it was "dd a" element of the page? When I tried to inspect the page, I had to find 10 different places for the ten names.

Comment: By examining the page's source code, the names were under an "a" tag but  since there could be many of the those, I stepped one level in the hierarchical, and the "dd" tags that contains an "a" tag was unique enough to retrieve the names.